# Qml anchors (якоря страницы)

Tags: qt5, qml

Проблема заключатся в следующем. Вот код:

```
//Page1.qml
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Page {
    id: page
    width: 400
    height: 400

    title: qsTr("Firs page")

    Button {
        id: button2
        y: 167
        text: qsTr("Button")
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 15
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 15
    }
}
```

Нужно, чтобы данное окно 400 на 400, при уменьшении или увеличении размера, меняло размер кнопки. Добавил строчку (anchors.fill: parent):

```
//Page1.qml
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Page {
    id: page
    anchors.fill: parent
    width: 400
    height: 400

    title: qsTr("Firs page")

    Button {
        id: button2
        y: 167
        text: qsTr("Button")
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 15
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 15
    }
}
```

Заработало, но выдает ошибку `"StackView has detected conflicting anchors. Transitions may not execute properly.". Якорь пытается взять точки у QQuickstackview. Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно или нет, но взял

```
height: stackView.height
width: stackView.width
```

Вроде работает нормально.